# Observable.defer vs Observable.just

Tags: rx-java

http://blog.danlew.net/2015/07/23/deferring-observable-code-until-subscription-in-rxjava/ discusses creating observables using Observable.just, Observable.create, and Observable.defer

Let's say I have this:

```
List<File> fileIOFunction() {
    // does some file io operations
}

OBSERVABLE.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

What thread do the file io operations run on if OBSERVABLE is:

```
Observable.create(
                new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<File>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super List<File>> 
                                     subscriber) {
                        subscriber.onNext(fileIOFunction());
                 }
```

If OBSERVABLE is Observable.just(fileIOFunction())

If OBSERVABLE is

```
Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<List<File>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<File>> call() { 
                    return Observable.just(fileIOFunction());
                });
```

Comment: You could simply try it by adding `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread())` to `fileIOFunction()`, implement both cases and run them.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about Thread.currentThread().  Attach getName() to print which thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *just* it will run on calling thread, because fileIOFunction() will be invoked eagerly. Defer and Create will run on Schedulers.io() due to *subscribeOn* and will switch to AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() due to *observeOn* (switch thread). Create and Defer are lazy.